# parameterless constructor issue with entity framework

Tags: entity-framework-5

I have the following code that is causing the parameterless constructor error with entity framework.  I've figured out that it's being caused by the if (search.Active) block and the dates inside there... but I'm not sure how to get around it.  How can I construct my dates so that EF will work with them?  Thanks.

```
var members = from m in Members select m;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.Letter))
            members = members.Where(x => x.LastName.Substring(0, 1) == search.Letter.Substring(0, 1));

        if (search.Active)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now < new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 10, 15))
            {
                members = members.Where(x => x.ExpireDate >= new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 5, 31));
            }
            else
            {
                members = members.Where(x => x.ExpireDate >= new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year + 1, 5, 31));
            }
        }

        return members.Select(x => new MemberListItem
            {
                FirstName = x.FirstName, 
                LastName = x.LastName, 
                MemberId = x.MemberId, 
                ExpirationDate = x.ExpireDate
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: The *exact* exception message would be more helpful than this mysterious *"parameterless constructor error"*.

Comment: Sorry, when I searched on the error message there were a ton of hits here on stackoverflow and it was mentioned that it was a very common error.  Anyway, here's the mysterious message - Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that this will solve the problem because EF might have problems to construct the `DateTime` inside of a LINQ-to-Entities query:

```cs
if (search.Active)
{
    if (DateTime.Now < new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 10, 15))
    {
        DateTime date = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 5, 31);
        members = members.Where(x => x.ExpireDate >= date);
    }
    else
    {
        DateTime date = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year + 1, 5, 31);
        members = members.Where(x => x.ExpireDate >= date);
    }
}
```